# Unknown symbol 'textbox1' in class container-gambas error

Tags: gambas

I had copied data from one form to another previously and it worked bt right now when I am trying to copy the detail of field 'PASSPORT' from login.form to from_to.form it shows an error.
here's the login.form
[image]

and here's the from_to.form with error

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls are not properties of their forms, and moreover they are not (by default) public.

In other words, you access controls by using a global variable having the same name as the control, and only from inside the form, as that global variable is private.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above the controls are private to each form and not visible to each other unless you make them public.

You are trying to access login.TextBox1 from another class.

To access login.TextBox1 from the from_to.class you must do one of the following...

- In the IDE on the login form select TextBox1 and set it's **Public** property to **True**.

or..

- Open the project properties and select the "Make all controls public" option. this makes **all** controls visible across **all** forms.